# using html entities inside “double-mustache” syntax

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am using Polymer 0.5.5. I have created a template block in which I am using some html entities. These entities are generated dynamically. Here is an example:

```
<template repeat="{{n in [1,2,3]}}">
 <span>&#64396;</span> <span>&#{{64396 + n}};</span>
</template>
```

The problem with this, the first span tag output the html entity perfectly, but the second span tag doesn't. If I `view source` for it, then I can see the valid character for the first span, but for the second span, I can only see html entity and it doesn't update the DOM correctly. Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.fromCharCode. For ex:

```
<span>&#64396;</span> <span>{{fromCharCode(n)}};</span>
```

and

```
fromCharCode: function(n) {
    return String.fromCharCode(64396 + n)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. But I wonder why I can't use `String.fromCharCode` directly inside double-mustache.

Comment: Inside the template you can't access String object.